# How to make an extension for JToken (Newtonsoft) in C#?

Tags: c#, linq, json.net, type-conversion, extends

I have some Web API that returns objects and collections, when deserialized I can get a `JToken`, which can be either a `JObject` or a `JArray`. I want to write an extension for the `JToken` type that will translate `JToken` to `JObject` or `JArray`.

I know that it is possible to make a parameter to select one of two types or to make two different methods, but I want to make one universal method for conversion.

How am I trying to implement such a task:

```
namespace App.Extensions
{
    public static class JsonExtensions
    {
        public static T To<T>(this JToken token) => (T)token;
    }
}
```

And getting an error:

> Unable to convert type "Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken" in "T".

Maybe there are more civil methods of solution?

Comment: `public static T To<T>(this JToken token) where T : JContainer /*or JToken*/ => (T)token; `

Comment: Still it's `var obj = (JObject)token;` vs `var obj = token.To<JObject>();` ... your extension takes longer to write

Comment: also if you don't know the type of the token maybe it would be bettter to use [pattern mathing](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/whats-new-in-csharp-7-0/) (see shape example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i made you example to convert to class

```
void Main()
{
    string json = "{\"employees\":[{\"name\":\"Shyam\",\"email\":\"shyamjaiswal@gmail.com\"},{\"name\":\"Bob\",\"email\":\"bob32@gmail.com\"},{\"name\":\"Jai\",\"email\":\"jai87@gmail.com\"}]}";
    var jobj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JToken>(json);
    jobj.To<Root>().Dump();
}

public static class JsonExtensions
{
    public static T To<T>(this JToken token) where T : class
        => (T)token.ToObject(typeof(T));

}

public class Employee
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
}

public class Root
{
    public List<Employee> employees { get; set; }
}
```

[image]

if you need to work with Tokens - use JContainer

```
public static class JsonExtensions
{
    public static T To<T>(this JToken token) where T : JContainer 
        => (T)token.ToObject(typeof(T));

}
```

and call would be

```
jobj.To<JObject>().Dump();
```

[image]